# sys.getsizeof() value doesn't increase with increase of float value

Tags: python, memory, sys

While playing around with `sys.getsizeof()`, I noticed that it returns higher values for `ints` as their magnitude grows, signifying that they use more memory:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(3)
28
>>> 

>>> sys.getsizeof(300000000000000000000000)
36
```

However with `floats`, I get the same memory usage regardless of magnitude:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(3.0)
24

>>> sys.getsizeof(300000000000000.111111111)
24

>>> sys.getsizeof(300000000000000000000000.111111111)
24

>>> sys.getsizeof(300000000000000000000000.1111133333333331111)
24
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof), I should be getting back the accurate memory usage of built-in types:

> > Return the size of an object in bytes. The object can be any type of object. All built-in objects will return correct results, but this does not have to hold true for third-party extensions as it is implementation specific

Comment: Floats have fixed precision, they don't grow arbitrarily large like ints do.

Comment: Try `print(300000000000000000000000.1111133333333331111)` and you'll see that the later digits have been discarded.

Comment: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name `float` comes from the fact that they are *floating-point* numbers.

To simplify, `floats` are stored as `a * b ** c`, where `a`, `b` and `c` each take up a certain *fixed* number of bits respectively. Therefore, intuitively, if `f` is a float, `f * 10 ** 10` will not take that much more space than `f`, since we only need to increase `c` by `log_2 log_2 (10 ** 10) = 5` (normally, `b` is a constant, such as 2).

The flip side of this, of course, is that we can only ever represent a certain number of significant digits with floating-point numbers, which is why you run into rounding errors after a while.

In Python, `ints` are fixed-point, arbitrarily precise *and variable width*. That means that an `int` can grow as big as you want it to be, subject to memory limitations. The amount of space it takes is proportional to its magnitude, since it must store every single digit individually (more or less), rather than having an exponent-based calculation, as in `floats`. Therefore, multiplying an `int` `i` by `10 ** 10` will require `log_2(10 ** 10) = 33` extra bits.

For completeness, I would note that in something like `C`, the corresponding `int` is, like `float`, fixed width, and therefore the equivalent `sizeof` will return the same value regardless of the magnitude of the `int`.

Comment: It's hard to tell where the cutoff point is, where `floats` will return significant rounding errors, but it seems if dealing with lots of numerical values that are somewhat large in Python, it's better to use float over int as you can save a lot of memory.

Comment: It depends on your exact use case. Memory is so cheap nowadays that unless you are specifically in a situation where you *need* a (low-precision) floating point number, such as deep learning, I would just go for `int`.